# Alternate CSS Url point to layouts 15 folder?

Tags: 2013

I am just wondering what would be the format to put the url in the ALternate CSS Url to point to a file in the layouts folder.

Right now I have 17,000 site collections, and the css file is in the root site collection Style Library which is fine, I can make changes fast.

However, when I do backup restore from production to QA, then on the QA environment, I see the URL to the PRODUCTION CSS and thats something I want to avoid.

How?
My idea is to put the css file on the layouts folder, but how can I set it to be relative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i dont get what you mean, but what i think you mean is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_layouts/1033/customStyles/customCss.css"/>
```

do you mean the above within a masterpage? sharepoint would know what the current site url is, it just wants to know where the file is begining from layouts folder and working its way through! so if you have:

layouts -> 1033 -> customStyles

all above are folders, going to 15hive you should see that.... customStyles is a custom folder to hold your css, you can have it as anything you want! customCss.css is the css file that you have stored within the folder.

**EDIT**

I get you! from the masterpage and layouts section from sharepoint ui!

yes you can do exactly the same! you should be able to add the url like so:

```
/_layouts/1033/customStyles/customCss.css
```

Comment: Not in the masterpage, in the site collection settings, master page, there is a setting called alternate css url, I need to know if I can set it to a relative url in the layouts folder and how?, can I use SiteTOken? or just _layouts, our ~